# Saving a reference to .innerHTML

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
var button = $A("#aba_but_del")[0];
button.innerHTML = Su.Ani.flipPane.p1;
```

But this does not work

```
var button_text = $A("#aba_but_del")[0].innerHTML;
button_text = Su.Ani.flipPane.p1;
```

Why?

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence, the `.` has highest precedence.  Does this mean that `.innerHTML` is being applied to `[0]`?

Comment: `innerHTML` is a _string_. When yo assign it to a variable, the variable holds the string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
button_text is a string, no longer bound to the button DOM object.
So changing it will not impact the button element.

2)
*Does this mean that .innerHTML is being applied to [0]?* Yes. "." and "[]" have the same priority going from left to right.

Comment: Also, you need to access .innerHTML on [0], because `$A("#aba_but_del")` is a jQuery search result, not an element.

Answer (score 2):

All primitives in javascript are immutable. This means that the following code just changes a different instance of a string:

```
button_text = Su.Ani.flipPane.p1;
```

In the first case button is an object referencing a DOM element. So when changing the innerHTML property value you are changing the DOM element itself.

Answer (score 2):

`button_text = ...` replaces the variable with the value.

`button.innerHTML = ...` replaces the property of the object, which in turn affects the displayed HTML because of how the setter function works for that property.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a reference to a property.

When you do like this:

```
var button = $A("#aba_but_del")[0];
```

you get a reference to the element, so later on you can use that reference to access members of the element.

When you do like this:

```
var button = $A("#aba_but_del")[0].innerHTML;
```

you get the value of the property, not a reference to the property. The value is a string taht you assign to the `button` variable, and assigning a different string to the variable doesn't change the first string, and not the object where that string was copied from.

> "The . has highest precedence. Does this mean that .innerHTML is being
>   applied to [0]?"

No. The `[]` operator has the same precedence as the `.` operator, as they are actually the same operator, so they are evaluated from left to right. Using `obj['name']` is the same as `obj.name`, but the `.` operator can't be used with a property name that doesn't follow the rules of an identifier, like a numeric index.

Comment: So...it was just a random choice that they put the `.` over the `[]` in the chart I guess...they are slightly different as `.` will accept only valid JS names while `[]` is not as restricted for accessing properties....I guess the important thing to know is whether you get a value or a reference back

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: Yes, the precedence is not in the order of the list, but the number in the leftmost column, so the operators `.`, `[]` and `new` all have precedence one. Also, the associativity matters, so for example the expression `new x().y` will evaluate `new x()` before applying the `.` operator, eventhough `()` has lower precedence than `.`, as `().y` can't be evaluated by itself without what's to the left of `()`. And, yes, the reason that your code didn't do what you expected is because of how references work, not because of precedence.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript has no pointers or such stuff. If you assign something to a variable, you overwrite the previous value. You want to assign to the `innerHTML` *property* of the DOM *object*, changing the page rendering.